# Mule Salesforce Create

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-studio

With Mule Salesforce Connector using sfdc:create, the document says we can send up to 200 records at a time (single round trip call). If that's the case, what benefit do we get using Mule Batch flow with Batch Commit and Salesforce (sfdc:create) within the Batch Commit?

Example create below.

```
<xml<sfdc:create type="Account">
<sfdc:objects>
    <sfdc:object>
        <Name>MuleSoft</Name>
        <BillingStreet>I live here </BillingStreet>
        <BillingCity>My City</BillingCity>
        <BillingState>MA</BillingState>
        <BillingPostalCode>32423</BillingPostalCode>
        <BillingCountry>US</BillingCountry>
    </sfdc:object>
 .......200 such objects
</sfdc:objects>
</sfdc:create>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please keep in mind that in Salesforce, the SOAP API Call Limit for a client application is up to 200 records in a single create() call. If a create request exceeds 200 objects, then the entire operation fails.**
Please refer reference from [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't that mean that even in "Batch commit" I can't have a size greater than 200? I'm trying to understand when to use "Mule Batch" while writing to Salesforce.